# Can the Web SDK child_changed return a promise?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

With the firebase Web SDK you can do:

```
commentsRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
  addCommentElement(postElement, data.key, data.val().text, data.val().author);
});
```

However I wonder if it's possible to return a Promise instead of the callback above? Just like the following works:

```
this.productRef.once('value') // Attach listener
.then(result => {
  console.log(result.val())
})
```

Thanks for the awesome work!

Comment: What's wrong with `commentsRef.once('child_added').then(…)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises are meant to be asynchronous tasks that complete exactly once. So I do something, and then it either gets resolved or rejected, and then that's it.

The `child_added` event, on the other hand, will fire zero to many times for each time the child changes. This is not suitable for a Promise, and so instead acts as a *stream* of events, not a single asynchronous task.